# Is it mandatory to enqueue any kind of Javsacript?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I am dynamically generating in a page some Javascript code depending on many conditions, however this happens in the middle of the page. As I have read that as a general rule it's better to enqueue scripts, I was wondering if this rule applies also to page-specific scripts. For instance:

```
$var_js = "<script type='text/javascript'>// <![CDATA [\n var username; var yearly_programme = {};var monthly_programme = {};var user_role; var timetables = {}; var topbuttons; var middlebuttons_years; var middlebuttons_courses; var bottombuttons; var regelusername; var policies; var regelpass; username = '".$wp_username."';user_role ='".$role."'; topbuttons=".json_encode($buttons_top)."; middlebuttons_years =".json_encode($buttons_middle_years)."; middlebuttons_courses =".json_encode($buttons_middle_courses)."; bottombuttons=".json_encode($buttons_bottom)."\n// ]]>\n</script>";
echo $var_js;
```

Is it better to save this string (some variables contain jQuery calls) to a file and enqueue?

For example I could remove the `echo` and change the above to:

```
$file = ABSPATH."temp/AH-".$current_user->ID.".js";
file_put_contents($file, $var_js);
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

What do you think?

Comment: No, not really required to put your dynamic JS into a file. Use [`wp_localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) or hook into `wp_footer` and print `$var_js` if `is_page(your_page_id_or_slug)`. Just don't mix up JS with the content, instead place it to the footer.

Comment: So I could create a global var in my page and "print it" in the footer? This will not scramble other scripts? has jquery inside....

Comment: Could you tell me exactly where to put this? before `</body>` or before `wp_footer()` ?

Comment: Try this http://pastebin.com/hsKTueZk

Answer (score 0):

> Is it mandatory to enqueue any kind of Javsacript?

Nothing is mandatory, but it is good practice. And since WordPress 4.5 it's actually quite simple.

> Is it better to save this string (some variables contain jQuery calls) to a file and enqueue?

There is no need to write a temporary file just so you can enqueue it. We can now add inline scripts using the `wp_add_inline_script()` function.

> What do you think?

Here's what I would do.

1. Separate the dynamically-generated javascript from the static part
2. In the header, register the static javascript
3. In the body, generate the dynamically-generated javascript
4. In the footer, enqueue scripts

Both the static javascript and the dynamically-generated script will be placed in the footer, the dynamic script after the static file.

```
//* Register our script that will contain all javascript 
//* that does not need to be dynamically generated
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_106269_enqueue_script' );
function wpse_106269_enqueue_script() {
  wp_register_script( 'wpse_106269', PATH_TO . '/script.js' );
}

//* Dynamically generate some javascript and insert it inline
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_106269_head' );
function wpse_106269_head() {
  $js = '<script>alert();</script>';
  wp_add_inline_script( 'wpse_106269', $js );
}

//* Enqueue our script and inline javascript in the footer
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse_106269_footer' );
function wpse_106269_footer() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse_106269', '', false, false, footer = true );
}
```